# Integration of $\frac{\tan(x)}{\cos(x)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there a simple way of integrating $\frac{\tan(x)}{\cos(x)}$?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. A simple substitution.

Comment: But first rewrite tangent as sin/cos.

Comment: $\dfrac{\tan x}{\cos x} = \dfrac{\sin x}{\cos^2}$

Comment: When in doubt, convert everything to sines and cosines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\tan{x}=\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}$, we have
$$
\int \frac{\tan{x}}{\cos{x}} dx=
\int \frac{\sin{x}}{\cos^2{x}} dx=
\begin{bmatrix}
u=-\cos{x} \\
du=\sin{x}\,dx
\end{bmatrix}=
\int \frac{du}{u^2}=
-\frac{1}{u}+C=\frac{1}{\cos{x}}+C.
$$

Comment: wow..but how is do you see that at first glance?!

Answer (score 5):

Note that $$\dfrac{\tan x}{\cos x} = \dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x} \cdot \dfrac 1{\cos x} = \dfrac {\sin x}{\cos^2 x}$$

Now, what would make a good substitution in the following integral:?

$$\int \left(\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\right)\,dx$$

Try $u = \cos x \implies du = -\sin x dx$

$$\int \left(\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\right)\,dx = -\int \dfrac{du}{u^2} = -\int  u^{-2} \,du = \dfrac{1}{u} + C = \dfrac 1{\cos x} + c$$

Comment: Very clear!! +1

Answer (score 5):

This is $\tan(x) \sec(x)$ which is the well-known table derivative of $\sec(x)$.

Comment: Please bear in mind that your answer could be considered somewhat intimidating. Clearly it was not well known to the person who asked the question, and since there is no explanation _why_ it is true, it may or may not be useful..

Answer (score 4):

Since $\tan\theta = \sin \theta / \cos\theta$ we are really calculating the following integral:

$$\int \frac{\tan \theta}{\cos\theta}d\theta=\int \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta} d\theta$$

Now, let $f(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $g(x)= \cos x$, so that since $g'(\theta)=-\sin\theta$ then  in truth we have:

$$\int \frac{\tan \theta}{\cos\theta}d\theta = \int f(g(\theta))g'(\theta)d\theta$$

And by the chain rule $f(g(\theta))g'(\theta) = (F(g(\theta))'$ where $F'=f$, in other words, $F$ is a primitive of $f$. This implies directly that $F(g(\theta))$ is a primitive of $f(g(\theta))g'(\theta)$. Now it's simple to see that since we defined $f$ as we did we have:

$$F(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$

So that $F(g(\theta))= 1/\cos \theta$ and so we have:

$$\int \frac{\tan \theta}{\cos \theta}d\theta = \frac{1}{\cos \theta}+C$$

Now you can check directly that taking the derivative of what's on the right gives back where you started.